# An alternative to reCAPTCHA, which is already solved and proven, BUT consisting on operations, images or questions, instead of distorted characters?

Tags: forms, captcha, spam, honeypot-captcha

I'm working on a service request form, between 5 and 10 fields (depending on the service). *And, possibly, a recaptcha that the Security team is asking us to add.

The case is a user requesting an on-demand service which is additional to a purchase (sometimes free of charge, sometimes involving a fee).

There's no validation of the purchase code or username with any DB. User will have to fill in names, contact phone and e-mail (with format validation only).

I've tried to push for options like "solve the spam without involving the user", or.. math operations, e-mail verification (link sent to user, which is also asking effort from the user's side), slider (question to answer with a switch), multiple choice questions... BUT Security isn't confident about these custom security checks.

**What will you say about the security of a custom option like this:**
Show a random image of an object (related to the seller business) and offer 3 possible options (radio buttons) for the user to answer the correct one**.
E.g: a)Pencil b)glasses c)dog

Maybe too childish, but easier to complete than a reCaptcha, for sure.

I need to keep it serious, but easy for the user. A gamified option could be too much for this form.

Or, **any ideas on a service similar to NUcaptcha that is secure, already functioning, which I can only insert in my form without building it?** Perhaps based on math operations or random easy questions **instead of distorted book lettering?**

thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're looking for alternatives to Captcha first and foremost.

[Perhaps have a look into this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743928/stop-spam-without-captcha), where some coding smarts are used to determine whether or not someone is a bot. I believe it's called a "honey pot".

You'll also find some good [solutions in this article](http://www.karlgroves.com/2012/04/03/captcha-less-security/), and [here's another one](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html).

Basically, you're trying to trick the bot into doing things a human would not do, rather than making it emulate a human.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of showing an image and giving the user a choice to correctly name it; a bot will have a (in the example case 30%) chance at a guess.

You want the user to have to enter the answer by hand, and not select it, for that  reason.

Comment: That's true. Thanks Evan! The math operations is what I will need. Something like the recaptcha but instead of blurry characters, an operation and a field to type answer. Hard to find...